# Visual Studio Project to setup/install several application command line

Tags: visual-studio, installation

Good Evening

I am looking for a .Net project where i can use it to install several software running command line (in silent mode)
i normal would use a batch file with wait command but i was hoping for something more sophisticated where i can output success or failed install.

appreciate your help

Comment: 1) A batch file itself can be more sophisticated to output success or failed install. 2) What kind of .NET project? 3) People usually use third party tools (like WiX bundle https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/net-and-net/bootstrapping/), but such recommendation is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio Project to setup/install several application command
> line

I think you could install a vs extension called [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects). Please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-deploying-a-visual-cpp-application-by-using-a-setup-project?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=On%20the%20Visual%20Studio%20menu,results%20list%20choose%20Setup%20Project.).

You only to use `Custom actions` tag to install several softwares you want.

When you create the setup project, right-click on the project-->**View**-->Custom Actions--> right-click on the **Install** and select **Add Custom Action** to add any softwares you want to install.

**Besides**, just as **Lex** said, use Wix tool to create a msi installer project which could several install softwares. See [this link](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/net-and-net/bootstrapping/).

Insatll [Wix tool](https://wixtoolset.org/) into VS.

And when you finish installing, create a project called Wix setup project, then modify its `Product.wxs` file:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle Name="..." Version="..." Manufacturer="..." UpgradeCode="..." Copyright="..." IconSourceFile="..." AboutUrl="...">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

    <Chain>
      <ExePackage Id="Dependency1" SourceFile="Dependency_package_1.exe" />
      <ExePackage Id="Dependency2" SourceFile="Dependency_package_2.exe" />
      
      //add any bundled install software 
     
     <RollbackBoundary />

      <MsiPackage Id="MainPackage" SourceFile="Main_package.msi" Vital="yes" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```